# getting the one value of a textbox in a foreach using codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

Hi i have this foreach displayed data in a page. And in foreach i have a quantity textbox. My problem is i want to get the value of a quantity textbox to be passed when i clicked update cart. How will i able to do that?
Here is my code below.

```
<?php foreach($cartProducts as $product): ?>
    <tr>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Items_0__Id" name="Items[0].Id" type="hidden" value="376" />
        <td class="product-image">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/<?php echo $product->product_image; ?>" alt="" width="80">
        </td>
        <td class='product-name'>
            <a href='#'><?php echo $product->product; ?></a>
        </td>
        <td class="product-price">
            $<?php echo $product->price;?>
        </td>
        <td class="product-quantity">
            <input class="fl qty-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-range="The field Quantity must be between 1 and 1000." data-val-range-max="1000" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Items_0__Quantity" name="Items[0].Quantity" type="number" value="<?php echo $product->quantities; ?>" />
        </td>
        <td class="product-total">
            $<?php echo $product->total;?>
        </td>
        <td class='product-delete'>
            <a href='<?php echo base_url().'cart/remove/id/'.$product->id; ?>' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Remove this item'><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

in this line of code here

```
<td class="product-quantity">
   <input class="fl qty-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-range="The field Quantity must be between 1 and 1000." data-val-range-max="1000" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Items_0__Quantity" name="Items[0].Quantity" type="number" value="<?php echo $product->quantities; ?>" />
</td>
```

i want to get the value to be inputed and passed the data to it

my controller

```
//update cart
public function update()
{
    $Items = $this->input->post('Items[0].Quantity');
    echo $Items;
    echo "test"; exit;
}
```

How will i able to passed the value upon the textbox is inputed.
Any help is muchly appreciated.TIA

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<td class="product-quantity">
       <input class="fl qty-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-range="The field Quantity must be between 1 and 1000." data-val-range-max="1000" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Items_0__Quantity" name="Items[0].Quantity" type="number" value="<?php echo $product->quantities; ?>" />
    </td>
```

to

```
<td class="product-quantity">
   <input class="fl qty-text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-range="The field Quantity must be between 1 and 1000." data-val-range-max="1000" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Items_0__Quantity" name="Items[]" type="number" value="<?php echo $product->quantities; ?>" />
</td>
```

And then you can read those values as follows in your PHP

```
public function update(){
        $Items = $this->input->post('Items');
        foreach($Items as $ItemPrice)
            echo $ItemPrice."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: i tried your code it seems only one value will work. then after i change the other values in textbox seems not getting the correct values

Comment: For every different value you need, create a new variable array (eg: name="SomeVar[]"), and run a foreach loop on the server side for that variable foreach($SomeVar as $ $value) echo $value;